# On macOS, how to open a new Chrome window instead of a new tab from terminal (i.e., Bash command)

Tags: macos

I want to open a new Chrome window via a Bash command on macOS. I know how to do it via AppleScript like this way:

```
tell application "/Applications/Google Chrome.app"
    make new window
    activate
end tell
```

But how can I implement it using a simple bash command? Thanks.

Comment: Related post over at [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic): [Open a new Browser Window from Terminal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/305901/253138).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one `open -na "Google Chrome" --args --new-window`

`-a`: specify the application
`-n`: open a new instance
`--args`: all arguments following it will be passed to the opened application